# MySQL Declare Exit Handler statement

Tags: mysql, handler

SELECT @x returns 1, when it should return 2. WHY?
*Notice the DECLARE **EXIT** HANDLER

```
-- Paso 1
-- DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test;
-- CREATE DATABASE test;
USE test;
-- Paso 2
CREATE TABLE test.t (s1 INT, PRIMARY KEY (s1));
-- Paso 3
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE handlerdemo ()
   BEGIN
      DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000'
      SET @x = 1;
      SELECT @x;
      INSERT INTO test.t VALUES (1);
      SET @x = 2;
      SELECT @x;
      INSERT INTO test.t VALUES (1);
      SET @x = 3;
   END
$$
DELIMITER ;
CALL handlerdemo();
SELECT @x;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html

"Notice that @x is 3 after the procedure executes, which shows that execution continued to the end of the procedure after the error occurred. If the DECLARE ... HANDLER statement had not been present, MySQL would have taken the default action (EXIT) after the second INSERT failed due to the PRIMARY KEY constraint, and SELECT @x would have returned 2."

Comment: I commented the `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test;`, because I accidently deleted my (test)database ..... 

Comment: The statement to which the DECLARE EXIT HANDLER should apply, should be in a block, beginning with `BEGIN` and ending with `END;` if you look at the examples given on the link you provided.

Comment: @Luuk take a look to the manual, code is more or less the same than in the example provided after this sentence: "The following example uses a handler for SQLSTATE '23000', which occurs for a duplicate-key error:..."

Comment: The example is a `CONTINUE HANDLER`, not an `EXIT HANDLER` 

Comment: Try: `DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000' BEGIN END;`.

Comment: still trying to understand why we need a scope for EXIT HANDLER but not for CONTINUE HANDLER...

Comment: "_... statement can be a simple statement such as SET var_name = value, or a compound statement written using BEGIN and END_ ...", see [DECLARE ... HANDLER Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html).

Comment: @capovawi I think you are missing the point of the comments (e.g. it is not a scope thing). The exit (or continue handler) executes exactly one statement or a block. In your case, it is the statement "SET @x = 1;", which behaves as expected. Leaving the rest of the line empty is not a "do nothing" statement. The statement ends with a ";".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process flow:

```
CALL handlerdemo();

--      DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000'
--      SET @x = 1;
-- DECLARE, none executed

      SELECT @x;
-- output: NULL

      INSERT INTO test.t VALUES (1);
-- table contains 1 row

      SET @x = 2;
-- variable is set to 2

      SELECT @x;
-- output: 2

      INSERT INTO test.t VALUES (1);
-- duplicate error, handler call

--      DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000'
      SET @x = 1;
-- variable is set to 1
--      EXIT stored procedure

SELECT @x;
-- output: 1
```